# What products will the following reactions yield?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Assume these 2 reactions. I must write the Lewis structures of the products.

1. $$\ce{C6H5COOH + CH3CH2OH ->[\ce{H+}] ?}$$
   (comment: A benzene ring + $\ce{CO_2H}$ on one end, I don't know its name)
2. $$\ce{CH3CH2OH + (CH3CO)2O ->[\ce{H+}]?}$$ (comment: acetic anhydride)

**My approach**:

For the **first** reaction I will get acetic anhydride ([source](http://www.chem.ucla.edu/harding/IGOC/A/acetic_anhydride01.jpg))

[image: acetic anhydride]

For the **second** reaction I will get aspirin and acetic acid.

**Questions:**

1. Is the above correct?
2. Is there a connection between the two reactions? Is it an intermediate step of some sort? What is the importance between the two reactions?
3. Why is $\ce{H+}$ added?
4. What is the benzene ring and the $\ce{CO2H}$ called?

Answer (score 5):

1. No, I hesitate to give the correct products since this is homework, but maybe some of what's below will help
2. Yes, the two reactions are both esterifications; converting an acid, an acid anhydride, an acid chloride, etc., to the corresponding ester
3. The proton is a catalyst, it is not consumed in the reaction.  It protonates the carbonyl oxygen, making the carbonyl carbon more susceptible to nucleophilic attack
4. benzoic acid

Comment: Well even if it is homework how will I learn if I don't see the right answer at least once?

Comment: Is this the only product of the first reaction? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethyl_benzoate

Comment: For the second reaction will I get CH3C(O)OC6H5 + CH3COO-?

Comment: Yes, you got the first one and I think you got the second one, but your alpha-structure is a little ambiguous.  You can find the second structure here  http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/content/dam/sigma-aldrich/structure3/016/mfcd00009109.eps/_jcr_content/renditions/medium.png

Comment: @ron In an esterification of un-symmetrical anhydride,  how to decide which part of anhydride gets added to form ester? Please reply.